# Conditionally change text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to conditionally change the text in cells:

Example: in B2 if the value is 'something' i want to change it to 'anything'

Can anybody help in this?

Answer (score 1):

either:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B2; "something"; "anything")
```

or:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2; "something"; "anything")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it 
If you want to replace value in cell B2 then

1) Use Find & Replace function (in Menu-Go to Edit>Find and replace) OR (Ctrl+H)
and fill data by choosing range like picture below[image]

Or you can use either of this if you want replaced value in different cell

`=REPLACE("something",1,4,"any")` 
`=SUBSTITUTE("something","something","anything")`